# css drop down hover not working in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I checked similar topics but none of those solutions did work.

Here is the site: http://www.antihasereilaclama.com/index.php

Here is the css: http://www.antihasereilaclama.com/css/style.css

MENÜ LIST is my css drop down menu. I tried these; reset.css, csshover3.htc, emulateIE7 meta tag. But none of those did work either. Also csshover3.htc is still on. That work for first level of drop down menu, but have a 2nd level under "Hizmetlerimiz > ilaçlama >" (You will see how it should be if you try on chrome of firefox)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

1. adding `<li>` tags to the sub-sub anchor tags - just as you have done for the sub anchors.
2. moving Google analytic code from above `<!DOCTYPE` to inside body tag
3. Adding the missing quote on line 168: currently:  `cellspacing=0"`

Answer (score 2):

The script stuff before the doctype is putting you into quirks mode. Move that into the head where it belongs.